# Redirect all stderr of a console and subsequent commands to a file

Tags: bash, bashrc

I know how to redirect `stderr` to a file or to the `stdout` when I issue a command: `command 2 > log` or `command 2 > &1` or even `command 2 > &1 > /dev/null`. However, I want to redirect all the `stderr` to a file since I open a bash console and thus all error messages of executed commands in the console would be redirected to that file. Is that possible? If so, what is the command to put in the `.bashrc`?

Comment: I think it is not a duplicate, since I want to run a command at every session that will log all error/warning messages to a file in that session. Let me make it clear, I want to write a line in `.bashrc` so that when I open a terminal, all error/warning messages that would be displayed in the screen are now written to a file (which I can see later), somehow like the `.xsession-errors`.

Comment: @cacamailg It's a duplicate in that sense that one of the answers solves your problem (not the currently accepted one though).

Comment: @HaukeLaging not exactly. For example `exec > >(tee "$HOME/somefile.log") 2>&1`, doesn't seem to do what I want; that is, if I run `vim` I get the message `Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal`.

Comment: @cacamailg OK, I should have written: One of the answers uses the right idea to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to log the errors but also see them:

```
exec 2> >(tee -a error.log)
```

Hmm, just tested that, and it logged the whole session. Anyone know why?

Comment: Works fine for me. (`zsh 5.0.2` and `bash 4.2.45`)

Comment: Well I don't want to see the messages in the terminal, just log them.

Comment: @glennjackman: because bash uses stderr to echo what you type.

Comment: Heh awesome. Here is some magic to do the opposite and duplicate stdout on stderr `exec 1> >(tee >(cat 1>&2))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
exec 2> log
```

The documentation states:

> If COMMAND is not specified, any redirections take effect in the current shell.

Comment: This doesn't work for me! I am using bash 4.2.37(1), on Debian stable. It says `bash: exec: 2: not found`.

Comment: @cacamailg The space before the `>` was illegal (with respect to redirection).

Comment: @HaukeLaging Probably it is my bash version. But thsi solution seem to freeze my terminal. Probably what would work (which I know it is not a good thing to do) is to `ln -s $HOME/error.log /dev/stderr`.

Comment: @cacamailg: if you redirect stderr to a file, then you won't see any bash prompts nor will you see the what you type echoed to the terminal. It's not that the terminal is frozen; you can type, and you will see the output (stdout only) of every command. It's just that you will be typing blind. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Ah! I see. Well I wanted that because some programs started from the terminal send a lot of warnings outside, which makes it full of not-useful messages making it hard to use. As such, if I had a way to do it for all commands instead of doing every time I issue a new command.

Comment: @cacamailg: you should be able to turn off excessive warnings, but you'd have to do that on a command by command basis. Aside from the terminal echoing issue, stderr is supposed to be used for error messages, and if you suppress error messages for all commands, you're going to often find yourself wondering why things don't work as you expect.

Comment: That is why I wanted a log file though :).